# Surround all rows in a root Xml node (eliminating the column name node)

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql

I have a table with only one column of type `Xml` and also named *Xml*.
Each row represents a `<recipient>` item.

```
<receipt>
  <memberid>55555555</memberid>
  <purchaseid>4408888888859447</purchaseid>
  <time>2017-02-01</time>
  <depID>50277</depID>
  <amount>1398</amount>
  <theme>Herr</theme>
  <parentgroup></parentgroup>
</receipt>
```

What I want to do is surround all these items in one parent node of `<recipients>` so they will look something like this

```
<recipients>
    <receipt>
      <memberid>55555555</memberid>
      <purchaseid>4408888888859447</purchaseid>
      <time>2017-02-01</time>
      <depID>50277</depID>
      <amount>1398</amount>
      <theme>Herr</theme>
      <parentgroup></parentgroup>
    </receipt>
    <receipt>
      <memberid>55555555</memberid>
      <purchaseid>4408888888859447</purchaseid>
      <time>2017-02-01</time>
      <depID>50277</depID>
      <amount>1398</amount>
      <theme>Herr</theme>
      <parentgroup></parentgroup>
    </receipt>
    <receipt>
      <memberid>55555555</memberid>
      <purchaseid>4408888888859447</purchaseid>
      <time>2017-02-01</time>
      <depID>50277</depID>
      <amount>1398</amount>
      <theme>Herr</theme>
      <parentgroup></parentgroup>
    </receipt>
</recipients>
```

When I run the query like:

```
SELECT [xml] 
  FROM MyTable
FOR XML PATH('recipients')
```

I get an extra `<xml>` node for every record and this is what I am trying to get rid of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Declare @YourTable table (ID int,XML xml)
Insert Into @YourTable values
(1,'<receipt><memberid>55555555</memberid><purchaseid>4408888888859447</purchaseid><time>2017-02-01</time><depID>50277</depID> <amount>1398</amount><theme>Herr</theme><parentgroup></parentgroup></receipt>'),
(2,'<receipt><memberid>66666666</memberid><purchaseid>9999999999999999</purchaseid><time>2017-02-01</time><depID>50277</depID> <amount>1398</amount><theme>Herr</theme><parentgroup></parentgroup></receipt>')

Select XML AS [*]
 From  @YourTable
 For XML Path(''),Root('recipients')
```

Returns

```
<recipients>
  <receipt>
    <memberid>55555555</memberid>
    <purchaseid>4408888888859447</purchaseid>
    <time>2017-02-01</time>
    <depID>50277</depID>
    <amount>1398</amount>
    <theme>Herr</theme>
    <parentgroup />
  </receipt>
  <receipt>
    <memberid>66666666</memberid>
    <purchaseid>9999999999999999</purchaseid>
    <time>2017-02-01</time>
    <depID>50277</depID>
    <amount>1398</amount>
    <theme>Herr</theme>
    <parentgroup />
  </receipt>
</recipients>
```

> **EDIT:**

Updated Answer due to Shnugo's background info.  As always, very much appreciated.

Comment: The empty `Path` and the Casting as XML did the job. Thank you!

Comment: @Disasterkid Happy it helped.  I have no idea why that works, I stumbled upon this by accident some time ago  :)

Comment: Hi, I added an answer with some explanation, why that works. No miracle...

Answer (score 2):

this is no new answer, just some background.

This "trick" works, because the resulting column is nameless.

Look at this:

```
Declare @Dummy table (SomeValue INT)
Insert Into @Dummy values(1);

--Query                                --Column's Caption
----------------------------------------------------------
SELECT SomeValue FROM @Dummy;          --SomeValue
SELECT SomeValue+1-1 FROM @Dummy       --nameless due to the calculation
SELECT ISNULL(SomeValue,0) FROM @Dummy --nameless due to the function's usage
```

Any kind of calculation or usage of a function will result in a nameless column. Try to use `SELECT ... INTO ... FROM` or `WITH CTE AS (SELECT ...)` with a not named column and you will get an exception.

In conncetion with `FOR XML PATH` it can be very important to know this. If there is a column name, the XML engine will use it as element's name.

Try this (thx John for the sample code)

```
Declare @YourTable table (ID int,XML xml)
Insert Into @YourTable values
(1,'<receipt><memberid>55555555</memberid><purchaseid>4408888888859447</purchaseid><time>2017-02-01</time><depID>50277</depID> <amount>1398</amount><theme>Herr</theme><parentgroup></parentgroup></receipt>'),
(2,'<receipt><memberid>66666666</memberid><purchaseid>9999999999999999</purchaseid><time>2017-02-01</time><depID>50277</depID> <amount>1398</amount><theme>Herr</theme><parentgroup></parentgroup></receipt>')
```

John's answer works due to the usage of a function

```
Select cast(XML as xml) 
 From  @YourTable
 For XML Path(''),Root('recipients')
```

Using `AS [*]` as alias works too

```
Select XML AS [*]
 From  @YourTable
 For XML Path(''),Root('recipients')
```

The best way - formally spoken - is this

```
Select XML AS [node()] 
 From  @YourTable
 For XML Path(''),Root('recipients')
```

Any silly function or calculation has this effect

```
Select ISNULL(XML,XML)
 From  @YourTable
 For XML Path(''),Root('recipients')
```

Whenever people use `FOR XML PATH` as concatenation work around, they use this without knowing. The typical `SELECT ', ' + SomeColumn` leads to an unnamed result. Without the `', '` there would occur a "strange" element...

Comment: As usual, most informative  Thanks for the extra effort and background +1